# React native rotate gesture

Tags: react-native, animation

I'm new to react native animations. I want to implement a rotation animation, How can I rotate this cirlce clockwise and anti-clockwise?

I've checked some documentations but couldn’t understand it very well[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD89o.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of tutorials on how you can do something similar with Reanimated 2:

1. [About that Dial Login](https://youtu.be/Th6WxfhZsAM)
2. [Intro to SVG Animations with React-Native ReAnimated 2](https://medium.com/tribalscale/intro-to-svg-animations-with-react-native-reanimated-2-78bd87438129)
3. [React Native Wheel of Fortune | Gesture handler](https://youtu.be/tc3G-bO1p8Q)

Comment: I've checked these documentations but still couldn’t find work around this.
I just need to rotate the circle anticlockwise/clockwise having 7 segments and increment the number by rotating clockwise and decrement no. by rotating anti clockwise while passing through each segment.
 Could you please help me to build this logic?

Comment: @HurmainKhalid this is very close to what you need https://github.com/wcandillon/can-it-be-done-in-react-native/tree/master/playground/src/RotaryLogin you just need to change UI and logic about what to do when you rotate

Comment: Ok I'll take a look into this. I really appreciate your effort.